# How to fix Dialyzer "Callback info about the '.....' behaviour is not available" error for new Mix.Tasks

Tags: elixir, dialyzer

I created new `Mix.Task` in /lib/mix/tasks/start.ex for my project

```elixir
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Start do
  use Mix.Task

  def run(_), do: IO.puts("Hello, World!")
end
```

Now, it could be run from console like this :
`mix start`

But I'm getting Dialyzer error, that `Callback info about the 'Elixir.Mix.Task' behaviour is not available`. What does it mean and how this could be fixed?

Comment: This could be the projects dialyzer settings missing some deps in the PLT, are you using mix dialyxer or directly configuring dialyzer? Can you post the ```project``` function from your ```mix.exs``` file, which carries the configuration.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Looks like I didn't have [Persistent Lookup Table](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/dialyzer/dialyzer_chapter.html) (PLT) options added for dialyzer.
In my case for 'Elixir.Mix.Task' behavior to be available for dialyzer I had to update mix.exs file and define for which modules dialyzer should create PLT.

```elixir
  def project do
    [
      app: :some_app,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.6",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      deps: deps(),
      # Added following line
      dialyzer: [plt_add_apps: [:mix]]
    ]
  end
```

dialyzer is added through [dialyxir](https://github.com/jeremyjh/dialyxir) in same mix.exs file like this

```elixir
  defp deps do
    [
      {:dialyxir, "~> 0.5", only: [:dev], runtime: false}
    ]
  end
```

`mix do deps.get, deps.compile`
And your dialyzer should stop complaining:
`mix dialyzer`