# How do I fix dialyzer unknown_function errors from dependencies?

Tags: elixir, dialyzer

I have a large Elixir (1.7.4) application and am running dialyzer (with dialyxir's latest version). I get a lot of unknown_function errors for functions that seem to mostly be in modules nested under packages that I have in deps. I found [How to fix Dialyzer "Callback info about the '.....' behaviour is not available" error for new Mix.Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51208388/how-to-fix-dialyzer-callback-info-about-the-behaviour-is-not-available?rq=1) (errors that I also have and that I expect should share a solution) which says that I should be able to add the apps to my mix.exs file, but that didn't seem to do anything at all.

```
       dialyzer: [
+        plt_add_apps: [:mix, :plug],
         plt_add_deps: [:app_tree, :staged_client]
       ],
```

I also have numerous errors:
`Callback info about the Plug behaviour is not available.` even after adding the plug dep to the apps as above.
Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong? Can you explain what needs to be listed as apps, if they are also dependencies?
If you have solutions please be specific. I'm very new to dialyzer and pretty new to elixir.

(p.s. Gotta say I'm impressed by the incredible accuracy of dialyzer. So it would be nice if I could get this noise quieted down so I can really go after the problems. Found a few sneaky bugs so far (and a lot of bad specs :-( ).)

Here's my def for project in mix.exs, with my app name changed, and the expression added to try Aleksei's solution for plt_add_apps (which hasn't worked so far).

```
def project do
    [
      app: :my_app,
      # version: "1.0.0-beta15",
      version: version(),
      elixir: "~> 1.7",
      elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env()),
      compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers(),
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      dialyzer: [
        plt_add_apps: Enum.map(deps(), &elem(&1, 0)) -- [:excoveralls, :hound, :mox],
        plt_add_deps: [:app_tree, :staged_client]
      ],
      elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env()),
      elixirc_options: [long_compilation_threshold: 120],
      test_coverage: [tool: ExCoveralls],
      test_paths: ["test" | Path.wildcard("plugins/*/test")],
      preferred_cli_env: [
        coveralls: :test,
        "coveralls.detail": :test,
        "coveralls.post": :test,
        "coveralls.html": :test
      ],
      aliases: aliases(),
      deps: deps(),
      build_path: build_path()
    ]
  end
```

A small sample of the errors, highlighting the mix and plug dependencies that I tried adding as apps, basic types that aren't recognized, and the Plug and Mix behaviours not found.

```
Finding suitable PLTs
Checking PLT...
[:arc, :arc_ecto, :asn1, :auto_linker, :bcrypt_elixir, :briefly, :certifi, :coherence, :combine, :comeonin, :compiler, :conform, :connection, :cors_plug, :cowboy, :cowlib, :cpu_util, :crypto, :db_connection, :decimal, :distillery, :earmark, :ecto, :eex, :elixir, :elixir_uuid, :etop, :ex_ami, :ex_crypto, :ex_data, :ex_doc, :ex_syslogger, :exactor, :exprintf, :exprof, :faker_elixir_octopus, :file_system, :flip_text, :floki, :gen_smtp, :gen_stage, :gen_state_machine, :gettext, :git_cli, :hackney, :hedwig, :hedwig_simple_responders, :hpack, :html_entities, :html_sanitize_ex, ...]
PLT is up to date!
Total errors: 880, Skipped: 0, Unnecessary Skips: 0
done in 0m59.28s
:0:unknown_function
Function Arc.Actions.Delete.delete/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Arc.Actions.Store.store/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Arc.Actions.Url.url/4 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Arc.Ecto.Schema.convert_params_to_binary/1 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Arc.Ecto.Type.cast/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Arc.Ecto.Type.dump/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Arc.Ecto.Type.load/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Arc.Ecto.Type.type/0 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Jason.decode/1 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Jason.decode/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Jason.decode!/1 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Jason.decode!/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Jason.encode/1 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Jason.encode!/1 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Logger.__do_log__/3 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Logger.__should_log__/1 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Logger.add_backend/1 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Logger.configure/1 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Logger.configure_backend/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Logger.level/0 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Logger.remove_backend/1 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Logger.remove_backend/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Conn.assign/3 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Conn.delete_req_header/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Conn.fetch_session/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Conn.get_peer_data/1 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Conn.get_session/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Conn.halt/1 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Conn.merge_resp_headers/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Conn.put_private/3 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Conn.put_resp_cookie/4 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Conn.put_resp_header/3 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Conn.put_session/3 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Conn.put_status/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Conn.register_before_send/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Conn.send_resp/3 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Conn.Query.decode/1 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Conn.Query.encode/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Debugger.__catch__/5 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.HTML.html_escape/1 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.HTML.html_escape_to_iodata/1 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Head.call/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Logger.call/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.MethodOverride.call/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Parsers.call/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.RequestId.call/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Session.call/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function Plug.Static.call/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function :hackney.stream_next/1 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function :public_key.decrypt_public/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function :public_key.encrypt_private/2 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function :public_key.pem_decode/1 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_function
Function :public_key.pem_entry_decode/1 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: Ecto.Changeset.t/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: Ecto.Query.t/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: Ecto.Queryable.all/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: Ecto.Queryable.t/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: Ecto.Schema.t/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: Ecto.Schema.Metadata.t/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: Ecto.UUID.t/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: HTTPPoison.Response.t/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: HTTPoison.AsyncResponse.t/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: HTTPoison.Base.body/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: HTTPoison.Base.headers/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: HTTPoison.Error.t/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: HTTPoison.Response.t/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: Integer.t/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: List.t/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: Logger.level/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: Logger.message/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: Map.t/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: Module.t/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: Phoenix.Socket.t/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: Phoenix.Template.name/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: Pigeon.APNS.Notification.t/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: Pigeon.FCM.Notification.t/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: Plug.Conn.t/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: String.t/1.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: String.type/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: Struct.t/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
:0:unknown_type
Unknown type: Swoosh.Email.t/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
lib/mix/tasks/one.gen.plugins.ex:1:callback_info_missing
Callback info about the Mix.Task behaviour is not available.
________________________________________________________________________________
lib/phoenix/endpoint.ex:1:callback_info_missing
Callback info about the Plug behaviour is not available.
________________________________________________________________________________
lib/phoenix/endpoint.ex:1:callback_info_missing
Callback info about the Phoenix.Endpoint behaviour is not available.
________________________________________________________________________________
lib/phoenix/endpoint.ex:1:callback_info_missing
Callback info about the Plug behaviour is not available.
________________________________________________________________________________
lib/phoenix/endpoint.ex:1:callback_info_missing
Callback info about the Phoenix.Endpoint behaviour is not available.
________________________________________________________________________________
lib/phoenix/router.ex:1:callback_info_missing
Callback info about the Plug behaviour is not available.
________________________________________________________________________________
lib/phoenix/router.ex:1:callback_info_missing
Callback info about the Plug behaviour is not available.
________________________________________________________________________________
lib/phoenix/router.ex:1:callback_info_missing
Callback info about the Plug behaviour is not available.
________________________________________________________________________________
lib/phoenix/router.ex:1:callback_info_missing
Callback info about the Plug behaviour is not available.
________________________________________________________________________________
lib/phoenix/router.ex:1:callback_info_missing
Callback info about the Plug behaviour is not available.
done (warnings were emitted)
Halting VM with exit status 2
```

Comment: Could you please share the exact warning/error message you receive?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I added a selection of the messages, if you are able to help assess them. Thanks.

Comment: `plt_add_apps: [:mix, :plug],` → `plt_add_apps: [:mix, :arc, :arc_ecto, :jason, :plug],` should help.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I got really advanced and set this:  
`plt_add_apps: Enum.map(deps(), &elem(&1, 0)),`
Sadly that made no difference at all. I still have all the same errors.

Comment: Try to remove the `*plt*` files and rerun dialyzer.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin There is no joy in Mudville, I've struck out. I removed the plt and plt.hash files from _build, ran a mix deps.compile per the suggestion from the other question I linked, and then ran dialyzer again. The output is no different. There must be something I have misconfigured, but I don't see anything obvious. Thanks anyway for trying to help.

Comment: I tried removing ../.mix/*plt to force the tool to rebuild the erlang and elixir files but that didn't help either.

Comment: [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68295347/how-do-i-fix-dialyzer-unknown-function-errors-from-dependencies#comment120744014_68295347) helped a lot! Thanks

Comment: Two years later and I still have not figured out what's causing this. It's still an issue. I haven't been focused on it, but I also haven't run into this in a number of other applications I'm working with (although they are all MUCH smaller).

Comment: I wonder if there is some symbol table that tracks the external modules to check and I'm overflowing that table. My list of exclusions only gets longer as time goes by. I now have about 109 modules excluded for unknown functions and 29 for unknown types. All of which combine for over 24600 skips. Not surprising since my list includes :erlang, Enum, Integer, Kernel, List, Map, String and all our other favourites. 
I'm on Elixir 1.14 now, which made no difference whatsoever.